# How do I hide sensitive information like plaintext passwords from the logs?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, logs, password

I do not have access to a Postgres installation, so I cannot check.

I am a security guy, and I'm seeing plaintext passwords in the logs:

```
create user user1 with password 'PLAINTEXT PASSWORD'
```

How can the DBAs change or create their passwords without the password in the clear in the logs?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429040/creating-user-with-encrypted-password-in-postgresql), which states you can use an md5 hash of the password, but then the hash is also in the clear. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you trust your DBAs (because you cannot enforce it), tell them to use the `\password` command of `psql`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Always prepare password digests client-side

If practical in your environment, use [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)'s `\password` command, or the underlying `libpq` function [`PQencryptPasswordConn(...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-misc.html#LIBPQ-PQENCRYPTPASSWORDCONN) ([src](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/interfaces/libpq/fe-auth.c;h=887ca5e9e1be78584d8e1358bec4653693ac832e;hb=HEAD#l1252)).

This pre-hashes the password client-side with `scram-sha-256` (assuming a modern postgres) then sends it with `ALTER USER ... PASSWORD ...`.

Other client drivers may have their own implementations, and if not, it's pretty simple to implement based using the client crypto libraries of your choice.

### Hiding passwords (or digests) from logs

It sounds like `log_statement` is set to `all`.

Unfortunately (AFAIK) postgres doesn't special case `ALTER USER ... PASSWORD` so there's no strong guarantee made that the hashed password won't get logged.

Ideally the libpq protocol would support a "sensitive" flag on bind params, and would support parameter binding for `ALTER USER/ALTER ROLE` statements. But it doesn't, and the server doesn't proactively mask out the password in the querytext either, so we get to work around it.

If you wish to prevent passwords from appearing in the logs while `log_statement` is set to a value that captures `ALTER USER` / `ALTER ROLE` then you'll want to override that when changing passwords. e.g.

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL log_statement = 'none';
ALTER USER ... SET PASSWORD ...;
COMMIT;
```

You must be a superuser to do this. Normal users cannot override logging rules.

---

It would be nice if PostgreSQL supported flagging some parameters to statements (or even functions) as security-sensitive and allowed users to request that they be masked in logs, `pg_stat_statements`, `pg_stat_activity`, etc. There is not currently any such feature - but hey, patches are welcome. If you're genuinely interested, post on pgsql-hackers before writing any actual code so you can get advice and comments, though. Alternately, speak to someone who does contract development.

In general PostgreSQL expects you to treat the logs as sensitive.

There are other areas where logging is a serious security concern. For example some of the `pgcrypto` functions take crypto keys as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer did not work for me on Postgres 9.4, for preventing the plaintext password from showing up in the logs.

What worked for me instead was generating the password hash locally :

```
$ username='some_user'; dbpass='some_pass'; echo -n "${dbpass}${username}" | md5sum | awk '{print "md5" $1}'
md5dcca63c0632e24746a19448231cac29c
```

Then inserting that :

```
ALTER USER some_user WITH UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md5dcca63c0632e24746a19448231cac29c';
```

(Security note : Depending where you generate the above, you may want to prevent your shell from logging to its history, or on a shared system you may want to use a *nix utility that will prompt for the password versus actually including it in the command. I happened to not be on a shared system, so that was not a concern for me.)

Comment: Very good.  One thing I'd add with some emphasis is that one simply should not set passwords in cleartext.

Comment: Yes, I considered this and mentioned it in the question. It is still not sufficient for my requirements.